# Problems with append()

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to add different arrays in Python to an empty list x by using x.append(). This is what I did:

```
x = []
y = np.zeros(2)
for i in range(3):
    y += 1
    x.append(y)

x
[array([3., 3.]), array([3., 3.]), array([3., 3.])]
```

The problem as you see is that it repeats the last result, and what I want is to get a list with different arrays within, such as: `[[3., 3.],[4., 4.], [5., 5.]]`.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: You can just change `y += 1` to `y = y + 1`. The former modifies the original array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commenting on your problem in detail.

Python works with the same instance of `y` all the time. 
At the end of your loop, you can think of your list `x` as: `x = [y, y, y]` and each change made on `y` was applied to each entry in the `x`.

If you want to have a unique copy at each iteration you need to make a full copy of the variable.

```
import copy
x = []
y = np.zeros(2)
for i in range(3):
  y = copy.deepcopy(y) # based on the comment it is enough  
  y += 1               # to put y = y + 1 (also creates a new copy)
  x.append(y)
```

I hope it helps you understand it a bit more what Python did (see also [Immutable vs Mutable types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types) for more details).

However, it seems to be quite inefficient.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to do! Thank you very much for the prompt reply :)

Comment: No worries, you can accept one of the answers to close the question

Comment: Unless you are using object dtype arrays, `y = y.copy()` is enough.

Answer (score 4):

You're changing the same array over the whole loop, move the creation of `y` into your loop:

```
x=[]
for i in range(3):
   y = np.zeros(2) + i
   x.append(y)
```

Comment: I know it may sound arrogant, however, in this solution, in my opinion, we miss the main problem that OP encounters. Working with mutable and immutable in Python. Don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

Use the full() function of numpy.You have to specify the dimension of array(in ur case 1 row ,2 clolumns) and the value u want it to fill with,ie value provided by i

```
x = []
y = np.zeros(2)
for i in range(3):
    y =np.full((1,2),i)
    x.append(y)
```

x

```
[array([[0, 0]]), array([[1, 1]]), array([[2, 2]])]
```